# batch search and replace strings in filenames with python

Tags: python, linux, filenames, rename

I am trying to write a small python script to rename a bunch of filenames by searching and replacing. For example:

Original filename: 
MyMusic.Songname.Artist-mp3.iTunes.mp3

Intendet Result:
Songname.Artist.mp3

what i've got so far is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from os import rename, listdir

mustgo = "MyMusic."
filenames = listdir('.')

for fname in fnames:
  if fname.startswith(mustgo):
    rename(fname, fname.replace(mustgo, '', 1))
```

(got it from this site as far as i can remember)

Anyway, this will only get rid of the String at the beginning, but not of those in the filename.

Also I would like to maybe use a seperate file (eg badwords.txt) containing all the strings that should be searched for and replaced, so that i can update them without having to edit the whole code.

```
Content of badwords.txt
MyMusic.
-mp3
-MP3
.iTunes
.itunes
```

I have been searching for quite some time now but havent found anything. Would appreciate any help!

Thank you!

Comment: For some small-and-dirty scripts to change file names Perl works better, especially due to great RegEx support and easiness of running system commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import fnmatch
import re    
import os

with open('badwords.txt','r') as f:
    pat='|'.join(fnmatch.translate(badword)[:-1] for badword in 
                 f.read().splitlines())   

for fname in os.listdir('.'):
    new_fname=re.sub(pat,'',fname)
    if fname != new_fname:
        print('{o} --> {n}'.format(o=fname,n=new_fname))
        os.rename(fname, new_fname)

# MyMusic.Songname.Artist-mp3.iTunes.mp3 --> Songname.Artist.mp3
```

- Note that it is possible for some files to be overwritten (and thus
  lost) if two names get reduced to the same shortened name after
  `badwords` have been removed. A set of new fnames could be kept and
  checked before calling `os.rename` to prevent losing data through
  name collisions.
- [fnmatch.translate](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.translate) takes shell-style patterns and returns the
  equivalent regular expression. It is used above to convert badwords
  (e.g. `'.iTunes'`) into regular expressions (e.g. `r'\.iTunes'`).
- Your badwords list seems to indicate you want to ignore case. You
  could ignore case by adding `'(?i)'` to the beginning of `pat`:

  ```
  with open('badwords.txt','r') as f:
     pat='(?i)'+'|'.join(fnmatch.translate(badword)[:-1] for badword in 
                         f.read().splitlines())
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! there shouldn't be any problem with files beeing overwritten. And allthoug my badwords file seems to indicate that i want to ignore case, this is not the case. but i do have following problem: ` File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 244, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unknown extension`

Comment: And runnning it with python 3 i get : File "/usr/lib/python3.2/sre_parse.py", line 653, in _parse                                                                                                                                        
    raise error("unknown extension")                                                                                                                                                                 
sre_constants.error: unknown extension

Comment: Do you control the contents of `badwords.txt`? If so, I would write the regex directly there, and avoid using `fnmatch.translate`. The code will be simpler, and using regex directly will allow for more versatile pattern matching.

Comment: The errors you are getting may be due to patterns in badwords.txt that do not translate into regex properly. Please post the contents of badwords.txt.

Comment: Getting rid of fnmatch.translate seems to do the trick! Great, Thank you! Gotta polish my regex up now though :)
Anyway here's my badwords.txt content: 
Made-4-me.com_
.itunes
.HDTV
.hdtv
-HDTV
-hdtv
.xvid
.3vid
-MUSIC

Comment: Good! just remember that the dot `.` means "any character except \n" in regex, so all the dots in `badwords.txt` should be backslashed: `.` --> `\.`.

Comment: Working like a charm! Thanks alot! For future reference: In the badwords.txt every regexp is in a seperate line and has to end with a space or the script will cut of the last character of the regexp.

Comment: Be sure to delete the `[:-1]` in the definition of `pat`:  `pat='|'.join(f.read().splitlines())`